# Change font color of TextButton on click?

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

I've read some tutorials and documentation on scene2d's UI capabilities, but I can't quite figure out how the skins work. I simply want a TextButton that changes color when pressed. I managed to get the background of the TextButton to change, but that's not what I wanted. It should have no background.

I would be very grateful if anyone could provide an example of how this could be done. It seems very simple, so I think I'm missing something obvious here. If a skin is involved, please write it programmatically.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out it was as simple as I thought, it just didn't work when I tried it the first time.

When defining the TextButtonStyle you can assign `downFontColor` the color you want your text to be while it is being pressed. You can also assign `checkedFontColor` the color you want the text toggle between when pressed.

Example:

```
TextButtonStyle textButtonStyle = new TextButtonStyle();
textButtonStyle.font = someBitmapFont;
textButtonStyle.fontColor = Color.WHITE;
textButtonStyle.downFontColor = Color.BLACK;
//Optional color to toggle between when pressed
textButtonStyle.checkedFontColor = Color.GREEN;
final TextButton textButton = new TextButton("Text", textButtonStyle);
```

This will produce a white TextButton that turns black when it is pressed. When the mouse/touch is released it'll either turn green or white, depending on the state of the toggle.

Answer (score 0):

You can also tint it, but the effect depends on the base color (if it is white, then it works perfectly, else it depends). Anyway, it's done like this:

```
button.getLabel().setColor(myColor);
```